# Open API (Swagger) non working in Spring Boot when adding context path

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, contextpath

I have a Spring Boot application exposing REST services that are easily called on addresses like

```
http://localhost:8080/<controller_mapping>/<service_mapping>.
```

I've been asked to modify my settings in order to add a context path and have my services to respond on

```
http://localhost:8080//gesev-mensa/<controller_mapping>/<service_mapping>.
```

Thus I edited my **application.properties** adding

```
server.servlet.context-path=/gesev-mensa
```

Everything works but I can't call Swagger on old address

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/
```

I get the error **Failed to load remote configuration**

As suggested, I tried to add property

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html
```

but problem persists.
I guess Swagger should be reachable at

```
http://localhost:8080/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/
```

but that doesn't work.
Any hint?

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html
```

from your properties,
And your swagger will be available in

`http://localhost:8080/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html`

As per your current configuration with,

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Swagger will be available in

```
http://localhost:8080/gesev-mensa/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
The first solution didn't work, while I verified that address http://localhost:8080/gesev-mensa/gesev-mensa/swagger-ui/index.html was reachable. Finally I decided to simply modify property springdoc.swagger-ui.path not to have repetition of "gesev-mensa" in URL.